# How to return multiple values ​with a function?

Tags: javascript, html, function, callback

In what way could I make the function return 3 values ​​to me so that those 3 values ​​would serve as input parameters for another function (as if it were a callback --which in fact, I think it is--)?

Until now, try the following (although it did not work):

```js
var resultado;
function num_2(repet){
 for (var i = 0; i > repet-1; i++) {
  if (i>=1) {
   return i + ", ";
  }else{
   return i;
  }
 }
}


function sumarr(a,b,c){
 if (a!="" && a!=null) {
  resultado = a+b+c;
  return "\n" + "resul: " + resultado + '\n' + "1: " +
  a + '\n' + "2: " + b + '\n' + "3: " + c + '\n' + '\n';
 }else{
  return "noting";
 }
}
console.log("\n" + "callback 2: " + sumarr(num_2(3)));
```

Comment: Can you please tell the expected output of your code?

Comment: return an array and and [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) it in your function params

Comment: You cannot do that in JS. You could pass the parameters as an array to help your case.

Comment: The for loop in `num_2` will only ever go through one iteration, because of the returns.  It looks like you meant to add `i` to an array or string, which you return later as a single variable.

Comment: I want the "num_2" function to return 1, 2, 3

so that "sumarr" use those 3 numbers as parameters

Comment: Sorry you can only return one thing from a function.  But that thing can contain other things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can return an array from the first function and pass each element to another other function as independent argument using Spread Operator.

```js
var resultado;
function num_2(repet){
  return [...Array(repet)].map((x,i) => i)
}
function sumarr(a,b,c){
 return a + b + c
}
console.log("\n" + "callback 2: " + sumarr(...num_2(3)))
```

If its hard for you to understand the first function so its same as

```
function num_2(repet){
  let res = [];
  for(let i = 0;i<repet;i++){
     res.push(i)
  }
  return res;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have two options; return a JSON object, return an array.

Returning a JSON object you can name the properties then modify the second function to accept the object and access the properties;

```js
var input = function() { 
   return { 
     a: 1, 
     b: 2 
   }; 
}
   
var output = function(obj) { 
   console.log(obj.a);
   console.log(obj.b);
}

output(input());
```

Returning an array and using that as the arguments to call the function with [apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) or with [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
var input = function() { 
   return [1, 2]; 
}
  
var output = function(a, b) { 
   console.log(a);
   console.log(b);
}

output.apply(this, input());

output(...input());
```

These all have the same result printing the following in the console;

```
1
2
```

Comment: @MaheerAli provided the answer for spread syntax which I've added here as well.

Answer (score 2):

with JS object :

```js
var Vals = Return3Values();

console.log( Vals.a, Vals.b, Vals.c );

function Return3Values()
{
 return {a:5, b:'hello', c:15 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to use the latest JS features, you can use [Destructuring Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) in your functions to solve this and clean up your code.

```js
function logLotsOfThings({thing1, thing2, thing3}) {
  console.log(thing1, thing2, thing3)
}

function getLotsOfThings() {
  return {
    thing1: "I am thing 1",
    thing2: "I am thing 2",
    thing3: "I am thing 3"
  }
}

logLotsOfThings(getLotsOfThings())
```